# Production ready Kubernetes cluster on Linux VM

Tags: kubernetes

We are running all our applications in Linux VM's and tried Kubernetes cluster on local Mac using minikube and it looks promising.

Interested in setting up Kubernetes on Linux VM's, but:
Is is possible to setup production ready cluster on Linux VM's?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Any pointer pls?

Comment: [Kubernetes provide guides for a lot of VM setups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#on-premises-vms) although I'd put [`kubespray`](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray) in that list too, it just won't provision VM's for you without adding some extra ansible.

Comment: I have done it. It is a big challenge especially when it comes to getting external addresses (using an ingress). But it is definitely manageable

Comment: Could you please share the details?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [`kubernetes/kubeadm` issue 465](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/465), setting up a cluster using VMs can be a challenge.

Using [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/introduction/) will help, since it provides secure network connectivity for containers and virtual machine workloads.
Use [Calico 2.6](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/getting-started/kubernetes/).